# Codeigniter Update cart - how to foreach indise array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach, shopping-cart

I have a problem in codeigniter update cart
this my view cart.

```html
<script>
 function update_cart(){
  document.forms["updateCart"].submit();
 } 
</script>
<h1>DAFTAR PRODUCT</h1>
<table style="width:100%" border="1">
  <tr style="background-color: yellow;">
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Price</td>
 <td>Aksi</td>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach ($products as $data):?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $data->name;?></td>
    <td><?php $hargapro = number_format("$data->price",0,",",".");echo "Rp.".$hargapro; ?></td>
 <td><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>cart/add?id=<?php echo $data->id;?>"><button type="button">Add to Cart</button></a></td>
  </tr>
  <?php endforeach ?>
</table>

<h1>DAFTAR KERANJANG SAMPAH</h1>
<table style="width:100%" border="1">
  <tr style="background-color: yellow;">
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>name</td> 
 <td>qty</td>
 <td>price</td>
 <td>total</td>
 <td>Aksi</td>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach ($items as $items):?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $items['id'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $items['name'];?></td>
    <td>
  <form name="updateCart" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>cart/update" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="qty" value="<?php echo $items['qty'];?>" maxlength="3" size="2" />
  <input type="hidden" name="rowid" value="<?php echo $items['rowid'];?>" />
  </form>
 </td>
 <td><?php $hargapro = number_format("$items[price]",0,",",".");echo "Rp.".$hargapro; ?></td>
 <td><?php 
 $totalitem = $items['qty'];
 $price = $items['price'];
 $xprice = $totalitem*$price;
 $xtotal = number_format("$xprice",0,",",".");
 echo "Rp.".$xtotal;
 ?></td>
 <td>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>cart/delete">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $items['rowid'];?>"/>
  <button type="submit" value="<?php echo $items['rowid'];?>">Delete</button>
  </form>
 </td>
  </tr>
  <?php endforeach ?>
</table>
<h3><b>Total Item : <?php echo $totalpro; ?></b></h3>

<h3><b>Total Harga : Rp. <?php $harga=number_format("$total",0,",",".");echo $harga; ?></b></h3>
<br>
<button type="button" onClick="update_cart();">Update Chart</button>
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>cart/destroy"><button type="button">Clear All</button></a>
```

and this is my controller update cart

```
// Update Product from Cart
function update(){
    $cart = $this->cart->contents();

    $data = array(
        (foreach ($cart as $c)){        
        array(
            'rowid' => $c['rowid'],
            'qty' => $this->input->post('qty'),
        ),
        };
    );

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    //$this->cart->update($data);
    //redirect('cart/show');
}
```

what I want to ask is:
1. How to update all of the items in the cart CodeIgniter?
2. Or how to insert function "foreach" in "array" as in update function?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to send the value of  `rowid` and `quantity` from your `form` to the update function .

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="quantity" value="" />
  <input type = "hidden" name="rowid" value=""/>
  <!-- OTHER FORM FIELDS HERE -->
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPDATE" />
</form>
```

And in your controller.

```
public function update()
{
    $data=$this->cart->update(array(
        'rowid'=>$this->input->post('rowid'),
        'qty'=> $this->input->post('quantity');
    ));

    $this->cart->update($data);  

    //redirect here
}
```

**Update**

To update all row at once you can use multidimensional array . It is well defined in [userguide](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/cart.html)

```
$data = array(
               array(
                       'rowid'   => 'b99ccdf16028f015540f341130b6d8ec',
                       'qty'     => 3
                    ),
               array(
                       'rowid'   => 'xw82g9q3r495893iajdh473990rikw23',
                       'qty'     => 4
                    ),
               array(
                       'rowid'   => 'fh4kdkkkaoe30njgoe92rkdkkobec333',
                       'qty'     => 2
                    )
            );

$this->cart->update($data);
```

Comment: thanks ..but , This can only be for one item in the cart.
how all the items in the cart can be updated in one function?

Comment: how to update all the items through an update form with one click of button?